# Смена цвета текста на гифку при наведении

Tags: html, css3, svg, анимация, hover

Всем привет
Недавно друзья заказывали билет на фестиваль на этом сайте https://bmfest.com/ (не реклама) и показали мне.

Мне очень понравился эффект с заменой цвета текста на гифку и я хочу узнать как это реализовано,желательно с примером.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Секрет в особом выводе фона и заглушке прорех до момента наведения.
Тогда просто скрыть заглушку и показать что фон вырезан особым свойством (`-webkit-background-clip`), хотя делали немного криворукие ребята:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url(https://bmfest.com/wp-content/themes/bmfest/images/map.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
   color: white;
  animation: animatedBackground 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: -300px 0;
  }
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li span {
  font-size: 100pt;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: Impact;
}

.v {
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
  color: white;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
  transition: all ease 0.2s;
}

.v:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='bg'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Text</span>
      <span class='v'>Text</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Низкий поклон милый человек <3

Comment: Барин принял Ваше уважение :)